# Regular expressions clarification

Tags: regular-expressions

I'm currently using the TheoryOfComputation book by Maheshwari and Smid to study regular expressions. In the book, examples were given as:

The language

$$\{w \in \{0,1\}^* : \text{the length of } w \text{ is even}\}$$

is described by the regular expression

$$((0 ∪ 1)(0 ∪ 1))^*$$

Some people in class said that it can also be written as

$$((0 + 1)(0 + 1))^*$$

Is this true?

Comment: I think the $\cup$ and $+$ are just different signs representing the same operation. See [Boolean Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $+$ and $\cup$ both denote the union operation.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, is word and string mean the same thing also?

Comment: Yes, this is another example of how terminology and notation may vary.